# POST falla en INSERT cuando viene varios datos

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache

Estoy usando `Codeigniter` trato de insertar datos desde una tabla en HTML a mi base datos mediante AJAX

Pero cuando esta tabla en HTML tiene mas de 37 líneas en la tabla el programa se cae.

Mi js.

```
function save_data(first_array) {
    var c_order_id = 0;
    var second_array = [];
    $("#table tbody > tr").each(function() {
        var celdas = $(this).find('td');
        var line = $(celdas[0]).html();
        if (line != '') {
            second_array.push({
                "line": $(celdas[0]).html(),
                "precio_unitario": $(celdas[1]).html(),
                "descripcion": $(this).find('input[name=descripcion]').val(),
                "m_product": $(this).find('input[name=m_product]').val()
            });
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>main/save_c_order",
        data: {
            "order": first_array,
            "order_line": second_array,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {}
    });
    return op;
}
```

Aqui mi controlador en PHP

```
<?php 


public function save_c_order()
{
    $document = trim($this->input->post('order[documento]', true));
    $codigo   = trim($this->input->post('order[codigo]', true));

    $data['documento'] = $document;
    $data['codigo']    = $codigo;

    $main_id            = $this->main->save_order($data);

    $array        = $this->input->post('order_line[]', true);
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        $line            = $val["line"];
        $precio_unitario = $val["precio_unitario"];
        $descripcion     = $val["descripcion"];
        $m_product       = $val["m_product"];

        $dataa['line'] = $line;
        $dataa['precio_unitario'] = $precio_unitario;
        $dataa['descripcion'] = $descripcion;
        $dataa['m_product'] = $m_product;
        
        $result = $this->cotizador->save_order_line($dataa);
      }
  }

 ?>
```

Trate de habilitar el `'pconnect' => TRUE,` pero igual sigue lo mismo.

Tambien he leido que puede ser el `httpd.conf`

Adjunto foto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 37 registros no es una cosa del otro mundo, más bien deberías ver por qué se cae o por qué va lento. ¿Quizá la tabla o la BD no están optimizadas?

Comment: Eso mismo pienso debe ser otro punto. Como puedo ver si es un tema de DB?

Comment: Un primer punto de depuración podría ser que imprimas la consulta en cuestión, la copies, y luego intentes ejecutarla **directamente en el SGBD**, si allí la consulta se ejecuta con fluidez, el problema está en el código (en el flujo del mismo habrá algo que bloquea o ralentiza la consulta), o en la capacidad del servidor, o en la conexión a internet, etc; si allí la consulta va lenta, quedará claro que el problema está en la base de datos y deberás empezar a analizar si tienes los índices adecuados, las relaciones entre las tablas, la no redundancia de datos, etc.

Comment: Solo hago un insert a la BD nomas

Comment: No entendí tu último comentario ¿?

Comment: Envió un array mediante ajax y el código colapsa o nose en un loop de INSERT datos a una tabla, no tiene nada de consultas grande

Comment: Es cuestión de depurar. Si crees que el problema es del código, haz primero una prueba simple de Ajax, para verificar que la comunicación cliente/servidor es correcta, que el servidor o el cliente no tienen problemas de conexión y demás. Luego, incorpora a esa prueba la consulta. Si falla, como ya dije, imprime la consulta y pruébala en el SGBD directamente. Si el código de inserción es largo o incluye otros archivos, revisa el flujo y/o esos archivos. Son cuestiones básicas de depuración, cuando algo falla ve de lo particular a lo general.

Comment: @A.Cedano okay gracias, las pruebas que he hecho y me  percate de algo raro que si en el LOOP del INSERT agrego 37 lineas funciona bien, pero si agrego 38 lineas o mas solo graba hasta la 37 ,como que para el proceso de grabado. Nose el codigo es resimple creo una order despues obtengo la ID para relacion con otra tabla llamada order_line

Comment: @A.Cedano adjunte una foto mas amplia. saludos

Comment: Poco se puede hacer con una imagen, hay que ver el código para quizá poder sugerirte algo. Aunque en problemas como estos todo es muy relativo, la lentitud puede deberse a la conexión internet, al estado del servidor o a otras causas ya mencionadas en anteriores comentarios. Si es posible muestra el código que refieres, donde ocurre la inserción. Otra fuente importante que te puede ayudar en esto, sería revisar los logs de error del servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano adjunte codigo

Comment: Prueba el código comentando esta línea: `// $main_id = $this->main->save_order($data);` y esta: `// $result = $this->cotizador->save_order_line($dataa);`, poniendo un  `echo` dentro del `foreach`.  Si funciona sin problema entonces descomenta lo primero y prueba de nuevo. Si funciona, es evidente que el problema estaría en `save_order_line()` y tendrías que verificar ese método. No sé si me explico, lo que te estoy diciendo son técnicas básicas de depuración que deberías aprender. Te vas a ahorrar horas/días rompiéndote el coco para encontrar un problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano probe ambos metodos y en la linea 38 se cae, creo que es un tema de servidor